# How can I retrieve data from phone call in WP7 app

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

My phone carrier has a number I can call (e.g. #1234#, including hashes) which returns my data usage of this month. 
Is there a way to programmatically extract this data within a WP7 app?
I know there is the PhoneCallTask, but that only calls a number. I don't quite see a way to get the data this phone call returns.

Answer (score 0):

Several carriers have webservices you can call to get information about your account. This information can be data usage, number of messages sent or minutes called and so on. I think you should contact your carrier and ask if they provide such services and how you can access them. In my opinion, this is the cleanest solution! ;)

**Update:**
I see you're from Belgium like me. As an example: here's the documentation on the API from MobileVikings: https://mobilevikings.com/api/2.0/doc/. Hope this helps!

Comment: That is indeed the best solution. Unfortunately, I'm with Mobistar, and they don't seem to provide such an API...

Comment: I did a quick search and the only API they have is one to create an application that can send SMS messages automatically or can send planned messages and you can track the status of them. But indeed no API like the one I showed. Perhaps you can contact them and ask if they will provide one in the future? :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with the PhoneCallTak . You can'y dial service codes via the PhoneCallTask .

Here's the info

http://windowsphonerocks.com/you-cant-do-this-using-phonecalltask-in-windows-phone/